# How do you detach an array of strings from shared memory? C

Tags: c, arrays, ipc, shared-memory, detach

I have:

```
int array_id;
char* records[10];

// get the shared segment
if ((array_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0666)) == -1) {
            perror("Array Creating");
}

// attach
records[0] = (char*) shmat(array_id, (void*)0, 0);
if ((int) *records == -1) {
     perror("Array Attachment");
}
```

which works fine, but when i try and detach i get an "invalid argument" error.

```
// detach
int error;
if( (error = shmdt((void*) records[0])) == -1) {
      perror(array detachment);   
}
```

any ideas? thank you

Comment: How do you know the `shmat` worked "fine"? You did not do error checking... and array_id is used uninitialized. *Never* post modified and incomplete code, *always* post complete and actual code we can compile!

Comment: @Jens Yes he did, he is checking that error is = -1. Im confused about the perror(array detachment) part, is that actually a thing in c?

Comment: sorry i left the error checking out but i did check after attaching. i know it worked fine because i didn't get any errors and i also assigned some strings and printed them out. and i've been told to use perror() instead of printf() O.o

Comment: @Ben No he didn't. I'm talking about the attach, not the detach. Detaching when the attach already failed is no surprise.

Comment: @Tim This is impossible to diagnose unless you provide a complete, self contained program we can compile. So far all we have is "Doctor, it hurts when I do something." :-)

Comment: what else do you want me to put in? I'm just attaching and detaching a shared memory segment, that code is it. i guess i'll put in the get part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shmdt()`, no need to convert the pointer argument to `void*` it will automatically take care of this .

Remove `(void*)` from `shmdt((void*) records[0]))`. It should be like this.

```
if ((error = shmdt(records[0]) ) == -1)
{
  perror("Array detachment");
}
```

And it will work.

Also in `shmat()` , on error it returns `(void*) -1` so your comparison will give warning.
so do like this

```
if ((char *)records[0] == (void *)-1)
{
  perror("Array Attachment");
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast `records[0]` when test for `==(void*)-1)`.

Comment: @alk :I saw the man page for `shmat` in that its given `(void*) -1`..That's why i wrote. Can you elaborate a little for me here because comparison of pointer to integer will give you wanrning won't it?

Comment: `records[0]` is a pointer (a `char *`). Any pointer can be assigned and comparted to `void*` without casting. This casting `-1` to `void*` is just a dirty trick to have `shmat()` be able to return some error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming attaching went well, `invalid argument` simply means that either the segment has already been detached, or the value of `records[0]` had changed since it was set by attaching.

Comment: My answer implies that the problem does not lie in how you attach/detach. The code is basically Ok. If you want to polish it up go for *Omkant's* answer. @Tim

Comment: you were right, i didn't modify records[0] and the error went away. @alk